# Flat Memory Model

Tags: память, пк, устройство

Опишите , зачем нужна плоская модель памяти ("одноуровневая несегментированная", "линейная")
В чем  ее особенности ? Просто в интернете нет нормальных обьяснений, по крайней мере не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё познаётся в сравнении.

Главный «антипод» *плоской* модели памяти — *сегментированная* модель, в которой всё адресное пространство представляется в виде совокупности «окон» — изолированных сегментов с разными правами доступа. Физически эти сегменты могут пересекаться, но для программы они всё равно остаются независимыми.

Особенность сегментов — их доступность. Программа может в любой момент либо явно обратиться к любому из сегментов, либо сменить сегменты по умолчанию (неявно используемые процессором при любом обращении к памяти).

Плоская же модель не использует эти «окна» — вам предоставляется сразу всё адресное пространство, без посредников и ограничений. Однако для изолирования данных друг от друга приходится использовать уже другие механизмы, непрозрачные для процессора (к примеру, виртуальную память, либо отображение банков памяти).

Я пишу именно «адресное пространство», а не «память», потому что в наши дни никто не работает с физической памятью напрямую, только с виртуальной, описываемой правилами отображения адресов, видимых процессору, на физические.

Comment: Хм, получается ,если представить на рисунке, сегментированная будет как [ [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]  ] - Где сверху адреса, а внутри значения,а несегментированная как [.................................] ,где внутри разграничения ,видимые только процессору?

Comment: "Пересекаться физически"-я так понимаю, речь об указателях?

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing `речь об указателях?` — нет, речь о том, что один и тот же участок памяти *может* покрываться несколькими пересекающимися сегментами. Тогда изменение какого-нибудь байта в одном сегменте тут же отобразится во всех сегментах, покрывающих этот байт.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing `Хм, получается...` — верно. Только эти `[]` могут ещё и пересекаться.

Comment: Можете это изобразить рисунком для наглядности? Не совсем понимаю, как они **перекрывают**

Comment: `[ ... .... .. ... . .. . .. . . .]` Тут код и данные находятся в одном адресном пространстве. Участки выбирает компьютер, как разграничить. 
А с сегментированной `[ [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][[][][][][[] ]` что? Как один участок перекрывает другой, если они независимы, и если указатель никак не замешан. Например, было бы понятно, если бы обращались указатели. **(int * p=&var)** В таком случае указатель, которому выдали бы участок память в размер (int) -4 байта, имел бы один адрес с переменной var, у которой тоже выделен участок памяти с размеров в 4 байта

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, при сегментной адресации у нас есть два уровня памяти —  «физическая», к которой процессор может обращаться по шине данных (*да, в эту шину можно врезать MMU для виртуализации памяти, но сути это не меняет*), и выстроенные поверх неё сегменты, которые доступны программе. Кстати, программа может гибко настраивать то, как эти сегменты ложатся на физическую память (в отличие от того же MMU, для настройки которого требуются повышенные привилегии, доступные только ядру ОС).

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, а насчёт указателей — при сегментной адресации они на самом деле состоят из идентификатора сегмента и смещения внутри этого сегмента (невыход смещения за границы сегмента строго отслеживается). Как смещение отобразится на физический адрес — контролируется процессором на основании предварительно выставленных настроек.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, считайте, что *сегментация* — это альтернатива *виртуализации*, при которой программе доступно не единое адресное пространство, а совокупность независимо адресуемых кусков, с точки зрения программы изолированных друг от друга.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing `Можете это изобразить` — проще описать. Пусть у вас есть два сегмента. Первый начинается по физическому адресу *0x0000*, имеет длину *0x20* (то есть 32) байта и доступен на чтение и исполнение. Второй сегмент начинается по физическому адресу *0x0019*, имеет длину *0x2* байта и доступен на чтение и запись. Как видите, последний байт первого сегмента перекрывается с первым байтом второго сегмента. Соответственно, в нашем случае адреса *0000:0019* и *0001:0000* указывают на один и тот же однобайтный участок в физической памяти. Как этим пользоваться — решайте сами.

Comment: Звучит все сложно, но кажется я понял.. **0x2**0 и **0x2** занимают один однобайтный участок, и получается, что они ссылаются на него как единое целое? хоть и одно "включает" другое на участке по сути.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, подозреваю, что вы недопоняли. Объясню по другому. Сегментация — это способ преобразования *сегментного адреса* (вида *`номерСегмента:смещение`*) в физический по правилу `физАдрес = информацияОСегментах[номерСегмента].база + смещение`. Причём `номерСегмента` может быть опущен, тогда процессор возьмёт его из настроек, основываясь на смысле текущей операции (чтение команды, работы с данными или работа со стеком). При этом ничто не мешает подбирать такие базы и размеры, чтобы разные сегменты частично или полностью разделяли общие участки физической памяти.